# Error while deploying on a staging server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I just reinstalled my staging server and I can't deploy my code. I installed pgsql and libpq-dev on the Ubuntu server 16.04 that I use. The file /srv/outils/www/projectname/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg_ext.so do exist.

Here is the error I encounter :

```
executing "cd -- /srv/outils/www/projectname/releases/20171119230417 && RAILS_ENV=prodtest RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
    servers: ["**.**.**.**"]
    [**.**.**.**] executing command
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] LoadError: libruby.so.2.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /srv/outils/www/projectname/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg_ext.so
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] /srv/outils/www/projectname/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require'
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] /srv/outils/www/projectname/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] /srv/outils/www/projectname/releases/20171119230417/config/application.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] /srv/outils/www/projectname/releases/20171119230417/Rakefile:6:in `require'
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] /srv/outils/www/projectname/releases/20171119230417/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] /srv/outils/www/projectname/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 ** [out :: **.**.**.**] 
    command finished in 2861ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

I checked all I could think of. It's the same error if I do manually the capistrano commands in the server.

Comment: Hi, did you try running `bundle` before migrating? I'm no expert really but I do seem to remember running into the same issue before.

Answer (score 0):

I was fixated on pg_est.so, but what I was missing was libruby.so.2.3

I uninstalled my ruby and reinstalled it, and now this step works.